# sliding panels using jquery

Tags: jquery

What is the best way to have a panel to slide down when a button is clicked? I need the panel to be movable. Are there any jquery plugins to achieve the same?

Thanks

Comment: By "movable", do you mean animate when the user clicks something else, or drag and drop?

Comment: i want to drag the panel around the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ***[.slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown)*** and combine that with ***[jQuery UI's draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)***, or you could use ***[jQuery UI's dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)***.

Comment: check out the link for specific use case examples.

Comment: I am aware of slidedown(), but do not I want the panel to  take the space on the existing page content. I want the panel to be like a separate page with its own contents

Comment: You might re-word your question with that then.  You sound like you want [jQuery UI's dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).