# jquery draggable boxes

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

This is an extension to a [question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064378/sliding-panels-using-jquery) yesterday. Based on one answer, I implemented a simple solution as follows:

[Draggable box](http://jsfiddle.net/RjbMQ/)

When you click on Click me, a box will slide down, but it not should occupy the DOM. How to make it overlay on the current page? I tried using z-index, but are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, all you need to do is use absolute positioning:

```
#draggable {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/g6jMF/